# Order in quotient group $G/H$ is not the same in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $p$ is prime, then

$$ord_{G/H}(gH) = p \Rightarrow  \exists m \in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}: ord_G(g) = mp$$

Can someone explain why $ord_G(g)$ isn't just $p$?

Comment: The claim is false, I think: $\;ord(2(6\Bbb Z))=3\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\;$, yet $\;ord(2)=\infty\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z\;$ .

Comment: It becomes true if you allow $m=0$ and say that elements that are not torsion have order $0$ (instead of $\infty$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is indeed false as Joanpemo as noted in the comments.
However, if $g$ is an element of finite order in a group $G$ or if $G$ is finite, then this is true.

Consider a group $G$ and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose $ord_{G/H}(gH)=p$ where $p$ is prime. Now, if $g$ has finite order in $G$ or if $G$ is finite, then either way suppose $ord_G(g)=n$. Then $g^n=e$ and since $(gH)^n = g^nH= eH = H= (gH)^p$, this implies that $p|n$, so there is an integer $m$ such that $pm=n$. We haven't used that $p$ is prime at all, so this assumption is redundant.

For an example, where the order is not $p$, consider the group $G:= \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ and the normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ generated by $2+8\mathbb{Z}$. Then $G/H$ has order $2$, so is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Taking the non-identity element (($1+8\mathbb{Z})+H$) in $G/H$, it has order $p=2$. Furthermore, $1+8\mathbb{Z}$ has order $2\cdot 3=3p=8$ in $G.$

Comment: $G$ is finite indeed, I forgot to mention that in my question. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, sometimes one forgets some details which might seem irrelevant, but which are actually necessary.